# Enhance i3-wm appearance

Tags: i3-wm

I am a student and therefore don't have time to program and customize stuff as much as I'd like. However I very quickly went from Windows to Linux and then adopted i3. However, as efficient and powerful as it may be, I find it ugly and not very user-appealing. At this [link](https://github.com/mkrnr/dotfiles/blob/master/.i3/config) I found a bunch of raw data to customize the i3-wm appearance. Naive and noobie as I am I just threw all of that into ~/.i3/config and relogged, and a bunch of errors came up.

What I want to know is if there is a simple, quick way to download and use a pre-made i3 theme,or if I'm going to need to delve deep into core programming mechanics to understand all that stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no themes like for example in KDE, Xfce or fluxbox with different title bar styles, animations, rounded corners, etc..

*i3* is a minimal window manager and - by design - offers only a limited amount of options to modify appearance. Those being [the font](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#fonts), [colors](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_colors), [border width and whether or not to display borders and/or title bar](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_border_style_for_new_windows).

Also, you have to keep in mind, that the *i3* configuration file (most of the time this is `~/.i3/config`) does more than just change the appearance of i3. It also contains all other settings like shortcuts, default layout, special behavior for certain programs, etc.. While you certainly may use other peoples configuration as inspiration, it is often not a good idea to just copy any configuration verbatim: You may not have the font defined there, outputs may have different names, some executables may not exist on your system, and so on. Also, what works well for *some guy on the Internet*, may not work at all for you.

**But** on the plus side, you will not have to "delve deep into core programming" to configure your *i3*. For one thing, the *i3* configuration is not a program, just a list of settings, all of which are explained in the excellent [i3 User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#configuring). There is also no need to set up everything at once. I would suggest to start out with the default configuration file, which should work on any setup (can usually be found at `/etc/i3/config`; also, if memory serves, *i3* should ask you if you want to create a configuration at `~/.i3/config` if there is none). Then you can just add or edit whenever you want to change something.

For example, if you want to change the colors. Just add [the example block from the User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_colors) and modify the colors to your taste. Save the configuration file and reload the configuration with `i3-msg reload` (In the default configuration this is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), there is no reason to re-login.

#### TL;DR

There is no such thing as themes for *i3* only whole configurations. Taking any configuration from the Internet may or may not work. But making your own is not that hard. It is probably best to start out with the default configuration (`/etc/i3/config`) and modify it with help of the [User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html) and just take inspirations from other configurations instead of copying them whole.

Answer (score 2):

if you wish, you can try a small program I wrote called i3-xfce. It will install a working theme on your desktop with a bunch of small utilities.

You can install it by typing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-respository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo add-apt-respository ppa:aacebedo/i3-xfce-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i3-xfce
sudo i3-xfce install
```

More informations here: http://www.github.com/aacebedo/i3-xfce

Regards :)